# Offload all "ImmutableMap/List" build work to compile-time?

Tags: java, optimization, guava, compile-time, minecraft-fabric

NOTE: This isn't specific to Minecraft Fabric.  I'm just new to rigid pre-runtime optimization.

I'm writing an API hook for Minecraft mods that allows the mapping of various tasks to a Villager's "profession" attribute, allowing other mods to add custom tasks for custom professions.  I have all of the backend code done, so now I'm worried about optimization.

I have an `ImmutableMap.Builder<VillagerProfession, VillagerTask>` that I'm using to store the other mods' added tasks. Problem is, while *I* know that the "put" method will never be called at runtime, I don't know if the *compiler* does.  Obviously, since this is a game and startup times in modpacks are already long, I'd like to optimize this as much as possible, since it will be used by *every* mod that wishes to add a new villager task.

Here's my current source code for the "task registry":

```java
private static final ImmutableMap.Builder<VillagerProfession, ImmutableList<Pair<Task<? super VillagerEntity>, Integer>>> professionToVillagerTaskBuilder = ImmutableMap.builder();
    
    private static final ImmutableMap<VillagerProfession, ImmutableList<Pair<Task<? super VillagerEntity>, Integer>>> professionToVillagerTaskMap;
    
    // The hook that any mods will use in their source code
    public static void addVillagerTasks(VillagerProfession executingProfession, ImmutableList<Pair<Task<? super VillagerEntity>, Integer>> task)
    {
        professionToVillagerTaskBuilder.put(executingProfession, task);
    }
    
    //The tasklist retrieval method used at runtime
    static ImmutableList<Pair<Task<? super VillagerEntity>, Integer>> getVillagerRandomTasks(VillagerProfession profession)
    {
        return professionToVillagerTaskMap.get(profession);
    }
    
    static { // probably not the correct way to do this, but it lets me mark the map as final
        professionToVillagerTaskMap = professionToVillagerTaskBuilder.build();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note that there is a good chance that the answer to this question is "Java just does it for you", but I wanted to get confirmation before I assumed that.

Comment: Java specifically _avoids_ pre-runtime optimization; it's generally built around the premise that slow startup is acceptable.  Most Java compilers do essentially zero optimization.

Comment: Are you sure that _this_ is what's causing your startup to be slow? Have you done any profiling? How many items are you adding to the map?

Comment: @Sweeper I haven't even gotten the thing to run yet; I just wanted to know if there was anything I could do to precompute stuff.  I guess there isn't. :(

Comment: My point is that you probably have better things to optimise (things that actually take up time) than "putting things into collections".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brief answer is: you can't do what you want to do.

> Problem is, while I know that the "put" method will never be called at runtime, I don't know if the compiler does.

The `put` method has to be called at runtime for your mod to be useful. By the time your code is being loaded in a form that it can be executed -- that's runtime. It may be the setup phase for your mod, but it's running in a JVM.

If the *source code* doesn't contain the registry itself, then the compiler can't translate it to executable code; it can't optimize something it doesn't know exists. You (the developer) can't know what mods will be loading, hence the compiler can't know, hence it can't optimize or pre-calculate it. That's the price you pay for dynamic loading of code.

---

As for the code you put up: it won't work.

The `static` block is executed when the class is loaded. Think of it as a constructor for your class instead of the objects. By the time a mod can call any of its methods, the class has to be loaded, and its static blocks will already have been executed. Your map will be set and empty before any method is called from the outside. All tasks added will forever linger in the builder, unused, unseen, unloved.

Keep the builder. Let mods add their entries to it. Then, when all mod-loading is done and the game starts, call `build()` and use the result as a registry. (Use whichever 'game is starting' hook your modding framework provides.)